# Google Custom Search - Search on querystring

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

Google's updated their custom search code last time I looked.  Here's our working code:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var cx = '011561302208175438083:iegdgk3oox8';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
</script>

...

<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

What we want to know, is how do we make this search box automatically search for a value when the page loads?

Answer (score 5):

```
    <gcse:search queryParameterName='q' autoSearchOnLoad='true' noResultsString='no results'></gcse:search>
```

this will automatically search for the q=MySearchString in the URL